# What it the WindowServer process for in macOS?

Tags: macos, process, macos-mojave

I'm not to familiar with operating systems but I would assume that

`kernel_task` ran by `root` is my core operating system in macOS.

I'm curious to what WindowServer being run by _windowserver is; and if I need it. It is the second biggest memory draw.

[image: Screen Shot of Activity Manager]

Answer (score 0):

A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=WindowServer%20process) for WindowServer process brings up Quroa as a first hit.

It lets you know that WindowServer is a process that lets your OS talk to your   Kernel so it is indeed needed and core to your computer working.